# how do I get my text to appear on top of my slider?

Tags: javascript, css, html, slideshow

I have issues with my slider. My text 
`h1` does not appear on top of my slider. I tried the `z-index` but it did not work. 
it seems that the image appear next to my slide and not on it.
[image]

here is my html file:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
slideshow-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 94px;
}
.slideshow-container .slider-text{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:#008080;
    height:510px;
}
.slideshow-container .slider-text h1 {
d
  color: #fff;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: center;
 width: 667px;
 display: block;
 margin: 130px auto auto;
 font-size: 35px;
 font-weight: 600;

}
.slideshow-container .slider-text p {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 17px;
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 700px;
 display: block;
 margin: 15px auto auto;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;

}
.slideshow-container .prev, .slideshow-container .next {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: auto;
 padding: 11px 18px;
 margin-top: -22px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
 border-radius: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 width: 48px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
}
.slideshow-container .next{
    right: 16px;
}
.slideshow-container .prev{
    left: 16px;
}
.slideshow-container .prev:hover, .slideshow-container .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration:none;
}
.slider-image {
  display: flex
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1"/>

              <div class="slider-text">
            <h1><span> why book an expensive hotel when you can book a cheap apartment</span></h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteur adipiscing
                    elit. Donec venenatis bibendum nunc ut convallis. Suspendisse in nunc unterdum quam pellentesque.</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: try to fix the code you posted, there is a lof of errors on it

Answer (score 0):

I would move the `<div id="slider-text">` before the `<img>` tag and then add the following to make it appear on top :

```
#slider-text {
   float: left;
   margin : auto;
   margin-top : 20%;
}
```

or

```
#slider-text {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20%;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   text-align : center;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. It seems that search bar now got lower, and the dots now disappeared.  And the text is underneath the picture .